# Android App - JSON - PHP - localhost --> NullPointerException by getting data from the php script

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm working now on my android app project and I have got a problem with the listView
Below is the code and the LogCat - Errormessage;
My Database is stored at the localhost and i am using a php script to get the mysql database

***Main - Activity of the App***

```
public class PlanActivity extends Activity {
String url = "http://10.0.2.2/phpBusplan/phpConnect.php";
InputStream is;
ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONObject json_data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.planlayout);

    RadioGroup rgZeit = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgZeiten);
}
```

**Here I get the data from the php script**

```
public void getData() {

    String result = "";
     ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    // http post
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Fehler bei der http Verbindung "+e.toString());
            }

        // convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
                 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                     sb.append(line + "n");
                 }                   
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            }

        // parse json data
        try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=1;i<jArray.length();i++){
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                results.add((String) json_data.get("IDHaltestelle") + " "+ json_data.get("HaltestelleName"));
            } 
                filllist();
            }
            catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            }

    }
    public <T> void filllist() {
        ListView listStart = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<T>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        listStart.setAdapter(adapter);;
    }`
```

**Log - Cat Message**

```
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{at.atn.android/at.atn.android.MainActivity}:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{at.atn.android/at.atn.android.PlanActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at.android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{at.atn.android/at.atn.android.PlanActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1487)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:654)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:326)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:216)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at at.atn.android.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  ... 11 more
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at at.atn.android.PlanActivity.filllist(PlanActivity.java:143)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at at.atn.android.PlanActivity.getData(PlanActivity.java:132)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at at.atn.android.PlanActivity.onCreate(PlanActivity.java:51)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
10-07 17:43:39.557: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  ... 20 more
```

**php - script ( name: phpConnect.php )**

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; 
$username = "XXXXX"; 
$password = "XXXXX"; 
$db_name = "XXXXX"; 

mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($db_name);

$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM haltestelle");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
?>
```

**json - data from th php script**

```
[{"IDHaltestelle":"1","HaltestelleName":"Schwarzenberg"},{"IDHaltestelle":"2","HaltestelleName":"Ulrichsberg"},{"IDHaltestelle":"3","HaltestelleName":"Aigen"},{"IDHaltestelle":"4","HaltestelleName":"Rohrbach"},{"IDHaltestelle":"5","HaltestelleName":"St. Owald"},{"IDHaltestelle":"6","HaltestelleName":"St. Stefan"},{"IDHaltestelle":"7","HaltestelleName":"Afiesl"},{"IDHaltestelle":"8","HaltestelleName":"Guglwald"},{"IDHaltestelle":"9","HaltestelleName":"Bad Leonfelden"},{"IDHaltestelle":"10","HaltestelleName":null},{"IDHaltestelle":"11","HaltestelleName":"Helfenberg"},{"IDHaltestelle":"12","HaltestelleName":"Haslach"},{"IDHaltestelle":"13","HaltestelleName":"Peilstein"},{"IDHaltestelle":"14","HaltestelleName":"Kollerschlag"},{"IDHaltestelle":"15","HaltestelleName":"Julbach"},{"IDHaltestelle":"16","HaltestelleName":"Nebelberg Ost"},{"IDHaltestelle":"17","HaltestelleName":"Sarleinsbach"},{"IDHaltestelle":"18","HaltestelleName":"HTL Neufelden"},{"IDHaltestelle":"19","HaltestelleName":"Niederwaldkirchen"},{"IDHaltestelle":"20","HaltestelleName":"St. Peter"},{"IDHaltestelle":"21","HaltestelleName":"St. Johann"},{"IDHaltestelle":"22","HaltestelleName":"St, Veit"},{"IDHaltestelle":"23","HaltestelleName":"Oberneukirchen"},{"IDHaltestelle":"24","HaltestelleName":"Herzogsdorf"},{"IDHaltestelle":"25","HaltestelleName":"St, Martin"},{"IDHaltestelle":"26","HaltestelleName":"Gramastetten"},{"IDHaltestelle":"27","HaltestelleName":"Linz Hauptbahnhof"},{"IDHaltestelle":"28","HaltestelleName":null},{"IDHaltestelle":"29","HaltestelleName":"Ottensheim"},{"IDHaltestelle":"30","HaltestelleName":"Walding"},{"IDHaltestelle":"31","HaltestelleName":"Gerling B127"},{"IDHaltestelle":"32","HaltestelleName":"Feldkirchen"},{"IDHaltestelle":"33","HaltestelleName":"Landshaag"},{"IDHaltestelle":"34","HaltestelleName":"Aschach Bahnhof"},{"IDHaltestelle":"35","HaltestelleName":"Hartkirchen"},{"IDHaltestelle":"36","HaltestelleName":"Eferding"},{"IDHaltestelle":"37","HaltestelleName":"Haibach"},{"IDHaltestelle":"38","HaltestelleName":"Kirchberg ob der Donau"},{"IDHaltestelle":"39","HaltestelleName":null},{"IDHaltestelle":"40","HaltestelleName":"Lembach"},{"IDHaltestelle":"41","HaltestelleName":"Niederkappel"},{"IDHaltestelle":"42","HaltestelleName":"Pfarrkirchen"},{"IDHaltestelle":"43","HaltestelleName":"Hofkirchen"},{"IDHaltestelle":"44","HaltestelleName":"Neustift"},{"IDHaltestelle":"45","HaltestelleName":"Oberkappel"},{"IDHaltestelle":"46","HaltestelleName":"Niederranna"},{"IDHaltestelle":"47","HaltestelleName":"Waldkirchen"},{"IDHaltestelle":"48","HaltestelleName":"Neukirchen"},{"IDHaltestelle":"49","HaltestelleName":"Peuerbach"}]
```

Hope you can help me
Thanks!

Comment: Whcih line is it: at at.atn.android.PlanActivity.filllist(PlanActivity.java:143)

Comment: Where are you adding your results List to the arrayadapter?

Comment: the line 143 is the blank line between creating the listadapter and set the the list adapter.... at the bottom of the code

Comment: i am new and i think i am adding it with the code

Comment: listStart.setAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results);
```

I think u misunderstood the way how to use the ArrayAdapter. Have a look at this really great [TUTORIAL](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: Ok gut du sprichst deutsch

Comment: ja glaube ich verstehe den Adapter nicht habe mir das Tutorial auch durchgelesen aber komme nicht drauf wie ich die ListView mit den Haltestellen fülle ... kannst du mir bitte einen Tip geben bzw helfen?

Comment: cant see your email
please answere here